# When under load, is it better to have one `aiohttp` `ClientSession` for an entire API, or one for each endpoint?

Tags: python-3.x, api, asynchronous, session, aiohttp

**TLDR**

Provided I am making approximately 40 total requests per second across about 20 fixed unique endpoints (some endpoints may be called more than others).

1. Is it better to have one `aiohttp` `ClientSession` for the entire router API, or one `ClientSession` per secondary endpoint I am calling?
2. (extra credit) Is this expected to speed up the slowdown described above?

---

I have a Flask API that is used to call other APIs, so it acts as essentially a router. The number of external APIs that it is calling is fairly limited (no more than 20 other unique endpoints), but the amount of traffic can get fairly significant (about 40 requests per second to be made). This service is made async so that we don't need to be waiting for a response in order to make the next request.

I was looking to speed up the service and found that a **vast majority** of the time (anywhere between 50% to up to 90%) of request time is spent for the secondary service to received the routed request! A potential timeline would look like this

```
1. t=0: Router receives request
2. t=1: Router processes and sends request to secondary service
3. t=8: Secondary service receives request
4. t=9: Secondary service completes and returns response
5. t=10: Router receives response and sends back response
```

While looking through the router code to find a potential speedup, I found that upon receiving every request, our API router is creating a brand new `aiohttp.ClientSession` which from the documentation is a very big [nono](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html)

Now that I am starting to write the code to allow the reuse of sessions (which would hopefully cut down on network time), I found the wording of `application` a bit confusing when it came down to whether or not to use one session for the entire API, or one session per unique endpoint. Since the secondary endpoints are fixed, it would be possible to have a dictionary with sessions, but I wasn't sure if the savings would be worth under this load. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312594/how-many-aiohttp-sessions-for-multiple-api-endpoints) seems to be asking the same thing, but the answer doesn't really answer the question, moreso just saying "its possible" more than anything else.